# Python messagebox program

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, messagebox

I need some help..

I want to make a python program that uses ***tkinter*** to show a message box. When the message box is closed once, i want to make 2 boxes appear. If the 2 boxes get closed i want 4 boxes to appear and so on...

I got the first message box to appear. If you close it a ***for loop*** wil start and activate the function that opens the new message boxes. Sadly it only opens 1 at a time, because I don't really know how to activate a function more than once at the same time.

**Here is my code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
x = 5

def open():
    messagebox.showwarning("Dragons..", "Cut off 1 head of the dragon and 2 more will appear..")

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.showwarning("Dragons..", "Cut off 1 head of the dragon and 2 more will appear.."):
        for i in range(x):
            open()
        else:
            root.destroy()

on_closing()
```

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

kind regards,

Sleek

Comment: I think that only showing one warning at a given time is a limitation (or design choice) of the library, you're calling the function correction.

Comment: What is the problem? Im able to get the code work correctly, like one after the other, messagebox keeps appreaing

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that i want them to open in parrallel. If one messagebox closes, 2 need to appear on the users screen. If those 2 get closed, I want 4 boxes to appear on the users screen and so on.

Comment: You can use `Toplevel()` instead of `messagebox.showwarning()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `messagebox` are modal windows, they stay open and block your code until the user closes them.

I you want to open several in parallel you need to do this through multiple threads.

You can try something like:

```
import threading

for i in range(x):
    threading.Thread(target = open).start()
```

If multithreading does not work then multiprocessing is the way to go:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
for i in range(x):
    p = Process(target=open).start()
```

Comment: Weird enough, its still the same for me

Comment: OK. I did not think about this, it is because python multithreading is not really a multithreading. You can try to use multiprocessing but this is really overkill for this simple task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jean-Marc, I will look into it and let you know how it goes.